# Trying to make a PHP code work in bluemix

Tags: php, mysql, ibm-cloud, devops

I've been working on a project that involves creating a PHP service, make it work locally with Vertrigo, and then upload it to IBM Bluemix.

The code seems to work just fine in local, but when trying to figure out the code in Bluemix, it starts failing.

The project is composed of 3 files: `index.html`, `client.php` and `server.php`. Apparently, the problem comes in between `client.php` and `server.php`. When I try to call a function which is defined in `server.php` from `client.php`, it will just skip the line where the call to that function is, and keep on executing the rest.

This is part of the client.php code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['saludo']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido'])) {
        require_once ('nusoap.php');

        $soapclient = new soapclient( 'server.php');
        $resultado = $soapclient->call('funcionsaludo',array( 'nombre'=>$_POST['nombre'],'apellido'=>$_POST['apellido']));

        $html = <<<html
            <html>
            <head></head>
            <title>Saludando...</title>
            <body bgcolor = "#9d1fc4" text = "black"><center><img src = "/images/3.jpg"></center><br><br>
            <center><b>$resultado<br><br><a href='index.html' style='color: #ffffff'>INICIO</a></b></center>
            </body>
            </html>
        html;

        echo $html;
    }
```

The part which is being skipped is where the call to the file `server.php` is made, which is:

```
$soapclient = new soapclient( 'server.php');
$resultado = $soapclient->call('funcionsaludo',array( 'nombre'=>$_POST['nombre'],'apellido'=>$_POST['apellido']));
```

Finally, I show part of the server.php file:

```
<?php
    require_once('nusoap.php');

    $server = new soap_server;
    $server->register('funcionsaludo');
    $server->register('getData'); 
    $server->register('insertData');

    function funcionsaludo ($nombre,$apellido) {
        return "<html><head></head><body>Hola $nombre $apellido<br><br></body></html>";
    }
```

As result, the function `funcionsaludo` returns a string composed of "Hola $nombre $apellido", but it appears to be skipped, because the string doesn't show on screen.

I'd also like to add that all 3 files `index.html`, `client.php`, `server.php` and the library used which is `nusoap.php` have all been uploaded to the default project folder inside IBM Bluemix DevOps Services, and they're not in different folders or anything like that. Furthermore, I don't see any error message in the Logs that could shed some light.

I appreciate any help given about why that function in the `server.php` file is being skipped. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your HTML variable you have a few tags, but for PHP to interpret it as text you should double/single quote it, like this:

```
    $html = '<html>
            <head></head>
            <title>Saludando...</title>
            <body bgcolor = "#9d1fc4" text = "black"><center><img src = "/images/3.jpg"></center><br><br>
            <center><b>$resultado<br><br><a href="index.html" style="color: #ffffff">INICIO</a></b></center>
            </body>
            </html>';

        echo $html;
```

Otherwise it's going to interpret as PHP methods and functions, and those don't exist. I suggest you change this and try again, if it doesn't work, open the developer tools on your browser and see if anything is rendered at all (e.g. page HTML structure).

Comment: Sorry, for you to use single quotes as I posted you'll have to concatenate the variables. If you don't want to concatenate, you'll have to use double quotes, but for that you'll have to escape the ones from your HTML tags then.